# "Not found" exception generated while trying to get CPU ID via WMI

Tags: c#, wmi, serial-number, hard-drive, cpuid

I'm using this code to fetch the processor id:

```
    public static string getProcessorId()
    {
        var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
        var moc = mc.GetInstances();

        foreach (var mo in moc)
        {
            return mo.Properties["ProcessorId"].Value.ToString();
        }

        return "Unknown";
    }
```

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit, Visual Studio 2008.
Unfortunately, a "Not found" exception is being raised by the mc.GetInstances() method call.

Here's a similar bit of code (fetch HDD serial):

```
    public static string getVolumeSerialNumber()
    {
        var disk = new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"c:\"");
        disk.Get();
        return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
    }
```

This code also fails - the "disk.Get()" method raises an "Invalid class" exception.

I've run this code with UAC turned off & on - nothing helps.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You WMI installation seems somewhat broken, I have tested your getProcessorId code on a Windows 7 with UAC on, and it works fine. "Win32_Processor" is a really standard class that should be there.

Here is a link to help diagnose WMI issues: [How to check the WMI repository before rebuilding it](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2014/08/08/wmi-repository-corruption-or-not.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! It works now.. I had to reset the WMI repository via "winmgmt /resetrepository" command.

Comment: saved my life! although the link is broken, there's an updated link from microsoft https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository/ba-p/373846